# TestNG: How to set attribute in test case listener and use it in custom reporter

Tags: testng

I want to set a custom attribute in `onTestSuccess` of my custom `TestListenerAdapter` and then use it in my custom `IReporter`.

I have tried following till now and could not make it work.

**MyListener.java**

```
public class MyListener extends TestListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr) {
        tr.setAttribute("custom", "customVal");
        Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(tr);
    }
}
```

**MyTestReporter.java**

```
public class MyTestReporter implements IReporter {

    @Override
    public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> arg0, List<ISuite> suites, String arg2) {
        List<TestSuiteResult> testSuiteResults = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
            Map<String, ISuiteResult> suiteResults = suite.getResults();
            for (ISuiteResult sr : suiteResults.values()) {
                ITestContext tc = sr.getTestContext();
                Set<ITestResult> passSet = tc.getPassedTests().getAllResults();
                Iterator<ITestResult> iter = passSet.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    ITestResult testResult = iter.next();
                    // Following prints the value as null
                    System.out.println("Custom: " + testResult.getAttribute("custom"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store attributes in `ITestResult`:

```
tr.setAttribute("key", value);
```

And from the reporter, you'll have access to your attribute:

```
Object value = testResult.getAttribute("key");
```

Comment: This way we can't set different values for different test cases in same class. I need a way to set value for a test case based on its test result.

Comment: I've just updated my response according to your needs: `ITestResult` can store attributes too.